# How to get the values as array from JSON data

Tags: php

{ 
    "signature" ="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! 
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! 
Rdrjn8f5He5sWeVtBNephmGdvhaIJXnY4wPc/zo7cYfrpn4ZUhcoOAoOsAQNy2! 
5oAQ5H3O5yAX98t5/GioqbisB/KAgXNnrfSemM/j1mOC+RNuxTGf8bgpPyeIGqNKX86eOa1GiWoR1ZdEWBGLjwV/1CKnPaNmSAMnBjLP4jQBkulhgwHyvj3XKablbKtYdaG6YQvVMpzcZm8w7HHoZQ/Ojbb9IYAYMNpIr7N4YtRHaLSPQjvygaZwXG56AezlHRTBhL8cTqA==";

```
"purchase-info" = "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!
```

i1vcmRlci1saW5lLWl0ZW0taWQiID0gIjQxMDAwMDA5MjkwMDA3NiI7CgkidmVyc2lvbi1leHRlcm5hbC1pZGVudGlmaWVyIiA9ICI4MjU0OTI4NTAiOwoJImJpZCIgPSAiYXF1YUFwaUJpZ0NvbW1lcmNlQWRtaW4iOwoJInByb2R1Y3QtaWQiID0gImFxdWFBcGlCaWdDb21tZXJjZUFkbWluUmVwb3J0aW5nIjsKCSJwdXJjaGFzZS1kYXRlIiA9ICIyMDE4LTA2LTAzIDE1OjExOjQwIEV0Yy9HTVQiOwoJInB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUtcHN0IiA9ICIyMDE4LTA2LTAzIDA4OjExOjQwIEFtZXJpY2EvTG9zX0FuZ2VsZXMiOwoJIm9yaWdpbmFsLXB1cmNoYXNlLWRhdGUiID0gIjIwMTgtMDItMjEgMTA6Mzk6NTkgRXRjL0dNVCI7Cn0=";

```
"pod" = "41"; 

"signing-status" = "0";
```

}

I'm not getting the value of purchase_info after decoding the JSON

NOTE: one more thing , every filed has semicolon at the end not the comma.
Actually I can't understand what type of JSON data it is. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's not a JSON.
for those data, i think you should use Regular Expression

Comment: Perfect Answer. Thank you @bardizba